# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x9eaa6b0

Tags: ios6, nsurlconnection, xcode4.6

When start  NSURLConnection some times I am getting these error.

But, not always get this error.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x9eaa6b0 {NSUnderlyingError=0xae8c730 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I suspect your URL might be bad.

Comment: It is working properly but, sometimes only getting error.

Comment: There is space in the url is reason for that mistake. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806235/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1000-bad-url-nsunderlyingerror-0xac926a0) helps you.

Answer (score 2):

There is space in the url is reason for that mistake.

```
NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&street=%@&street2=&city=%@&state=%@&
zipcode=%@&candidates=10", address.address2,address.city, address.state, address.zip5];
NSLog(@"BAD URL - %@",urlString ); // there is space in url

NSString *encodedUrl = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@" CORRECT URL - %@", encodedUrl); // url encode that space by %20


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL RLWithString:encodedUrl]];
```